# Sometimes renderer is getting fired and sometimes not, when trying to display a dynamic column

Tags: extjs, rally

I am trying to create a grid in which the dynamic column Cost of Delay is added. I have given the dataIndex as c_JobSizeWSJF (that.JobSizeField) and given the value of cost of delay in renderer. But, ***Sometimes renderer is getting fired and sometimes it is not***.When it is not, it is taking the c_JobSizeWSJF value from store and printing it in the grid. That means, Cost of Delay WSJF is showing up the same value as that of Job Size WSJF where as Cost of delay needs to show up differently as the sum of RR/OE Value, TimeCriticality, Business Value. Can anyone please help me..

You can refer the below code.

```
{
  dataIndex: that.JobSizeField,
  text: 'Cost Of Delay WSJF',
  align: 'center',
  hidden: false,
  renderer: function (t, meta, record) {
    var data = record.getData();
    var costOfDelay = (record.get(that.UserBusinessValueField) + 
         record.get(that.RROEValueField) + 
         record.get(that.TimeCriticalityField));
         return costOfDelay;
                }
         },{
           dataIndex: that.JobSizeField,
           text: 'Job Size WSJF',
           align: 'center',
         }
```

It would be really appreciated for quick help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "updater" function of a column 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-updater

Comment: I have looked at the updater function. But, If I put the updater, the flow itself is not going to updater and Cost of Delay WSJF is printing that.JobSizeField instead

Answer (score 0):

I would not have duplicate "dataIndex" if I were you. If it is not an absolute need for you to give your dynamic column a dataIndex, then you could simply not give it one. Otherwise, try to provide your column with another dataIndex.

Answer (score 0):

The renderer is fired when the underlying store's field is updated for the record. You can make this happen by adding the dynamic field to the record (but do NOT do a record.save()). If you want to have a record updated and also have a dynamic field then you will most likely have to manage two stores in your app, the first is for the grid and the second is for the save.

I create a dynamic column in a grid here: https://github.com/nikantonelli/discussions/blob/b34dadde423255b7a0d84db36daa21c0f2622b25/App.js#L145

To get it to always update on load, I do a two stage process, the first defines an initial value (i.e. "Fetching..." in my case), and then a second one to update the record with the fetched value that then triggers a grid update.

You might be able to adapt this sort of coding to what you need.

You might also want to look at another of my apps for tips: https://github.com/nikantonelli/WSJFBoard/blob/076bd676ad81412c423808533f95f2f85ac7e41e/App.js#L591